# I am getting bad request from the server when making DELETE request

Tags: rest, httprequest, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking shared client in order to make request to the REST server.

My code for delete is:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[[ApiClient sharedClient] deletePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/%@/venues/%@/", appDelegate.currentUser.userId, venue.venueId] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"venue deleted from saved");
}  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    NSLog(error.description);
}];
```

When I am configuring the client, I am adding:

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];    
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];    
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];    
[self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
```

POST request is working fine, but there is a problem with the DELETE request. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at the error and check what is going wrong. If there error is not helpful, then you will need to use a proxy (perhaps [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com)) and see exactly what is happening with the request and why the server does not like it.